# ListView and Data Models - Blackberry

Tags: json, qml, blackberry-10

I'm developing for the Blackberry 10.

I'm attempting to save and load a JSON data model into a listview in my app. It loads up initially via a couple lines of C++ in the app.cpp file before switching control to the QML file. However, I don't know how to save new cells into this JSON database. I don't know how to reload the ListView after I save. Finally, I don't know the restrictions regarding what I can and cannot save in a JSON database. Can anyone offer some assistance? Should I even be using a JSON model or should it be a QML or even XML? Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

Some more information about what you are doing here would be helpful in order to provide an answer. JSON is a format used to contain and represent objects in a string, it is not a database.  Typically working with a ListView requires creating a ListModel that contains your data and is rendered by the ListView.  When working with a ListModel you have access to a variety of functions as documented at http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/qt4/qml-listmodel.html . It is not clear from your question what you are actually doing though I would suggest posting your code to make everything clear.